# I had an SOC with two coprocessors R52 and A55. Both had PMU registers. Is there any possibility to acees both PMU registers from single code

Tags: c, assembly, arm, inline-assembly, multicore

I use the code below to access the PMU register of the core A55. Is there any similar way to access the same register on the R52?

```
asm volatile("mrs %0, pmccntr_el0" : "=r" (value));
```

I want access the value of register from both processor.

Comment: Its not single code. I meant it as two adjacent code

Answer (score 1):

From the R52 TRM, the PCMCNTR is CRn=9, Op1=0, CRm=c14, Op2=0 and the following text,

> The PMU counters and their associated control registers are accessible from the internal non-debug system register interface with MCR and MRC instructions.

The core is based on the AArch32 ISA and uses the 'co-processor' instructions.  An equivalent is,

```
asm volatile("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c14, 0" : "=r" (value));
```

The reference is from section 12 of the Cortex-R52 manual.  Table 12-1 details the co-processor op-code parameters.

Comment: Note: I don't have an R52 to try this on.  Some assembler may need '#0', depending on the tools you have.  I guess it is gcc based tools.  I highly suggest you download all documentation from the silicon vendor and ARM regarding the system you have.  There are permutations of 'TRM', user guide, implementers guide, electronics properties and programmer guides.  So you need to look for all of them from each vendor.

Comment: Other example documents are Arm Architecture Reference Manual Supplement Armv8, for Armv8-R architecture profile.  So, you have the specific core and architecture documents.  Some relevant understanding will be found in the implementers guide.  Often the vendor (NXP,STM,Broadcom,etc) documents will make a vague reference to an implementing parameter (HDL build time configuration of logic).